# Python error handling for FTP hang / 421 timeout

Tags: python, error-handling, ftp, timeout, ftplib

I have a script (below) that pushes an html file to a server. It WORKS 95% of the time. However, about 5% of the time, the server fails and the attempt to connect hangs. It stalls for 15 minutes (900 seconds) and then fails.

```
    ftp = FTP('[FTP ADDRESS HERE]')
    ftp.login('[USERNAME]','[PASSWORD]')
    converted_HTML_string = io.BytesIO(HTML_string)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR public_html/home.html', converted_HTML_string)
```

Again, this works 95% of the time. In the 5% when it doesn't, if I manually interrupt it when it hangs and simply re-run the request again -- then it works. It seems to be caused by temporary server glitches. I have no control over the server quality.

The real problem is that the hang is too long. What I want to be able to set a time limit (like 30 seconds) on how long it hangs, and then have code that says "re-run this ftp command until it succeeds."

Is that possible? Is there another way I should handle this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The channel timeout is set on the ftp server.  Some interfaces (such as FileZilla) allow you to configure your channel timeout.  Fortunately, Python's FTP package is one of these.  See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) for further details.
In the meantime, just try the timeout parameter:

```
ftp = FTP('[FTP ADDRESS HERE]', timeout=30)
```

---

Maxim Lott (OP) was able to catch the timeout error with the following, which re-tries the connection until it works:

```
import socket 
except socket.timeout, e:
```

Comment: Thank you. In case it helps anyone else, I was able to catch the timeout error with the following, which enables me to re-try the connection until it works:

Comment: import socket   [paragraph here]  
    except socket.timeout, e:

Comment: I'm adding your explanation to this answer, to give it greater visibility.

Answer (score 2):

This error had me thinking fo a while.

I made an exception in an infinite loop while True

- so when it happens it still True
- then I call my function ftp_connect_to_site() that is inside a class named RemoteTar

This function is going to reconnect you if this exception happens Not the best Idea.

am a beginner in python that all I could think of

```
          except ftplib.error_temp  as e:
               print('Time run out reconnect: ',e)
               RemoteTar.ftp_connect_to_site()
```